# PDO fetch_ASSOC to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I have a query, retrieves data without a problem.

```
print_r(array('data'=> $stmtdata->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))));
print_r($jsonArray);
```

De json looks like, unfortenately I need a slidely different json stucture:

> {"data":[{"primkeyid":"AX1", "name":"Jan" , "age":81} ]}

I prefere to have the output of the JSON:

> {"data":[{"ROWID":0 , "values":{"primkeyid":"AX1", "name":"Jan" , "age":81} ]}

I don't want to loop through the array to add a ROWID , I looked for array merge functions, just a quick and easy way to add an index.

Comment: And why do you need `ROWID`?

Comment: "*I don't want to loop through the array to add a ROWID*" what do you think array merge or whatever function would do? Yes exactly that: loop over the array and combine the rows.... I don't want to give you an answer if you are too lazy to loop over an object to fix your problem.

Comment: Just cant find the answer  ... ... fetch_group ... I think there's only one way... looping through.

Comment: There is an index already. No need to add another one

Comment: I need to because the json-output must be of a specific structure, the json is input for editableGrid.  http://www.editablegrid.net/en/

Answer (score 0):

`fetchAll()` will take all the rows and store them in an array.

If you ever find your self needing to modify that data structure, you must use `fetch()` instead in order to customize it. Since `fetch` get one record at the time, you have to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible, the json (output) needs to be manualy constructed.
Thanks for all replies and suggestions.